# Start foreground notification method

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like to ask if someone can give me an example that uses `NotificationCompat.Builder` with a foreground service. Can anyone do that please?

```
public void onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder  mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder ( this) 
       .setContentTitle("somthing");
    mNotificationManager.notify (mNotificationId,mNotifyBuilder.build());

}
```

When I use this in the foreground it refuses, so how can i use them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html):

> At a minimum, all notifications consist of a base layout, including:
>
> - The notification's icon. The icon symbolizes the originating app. It may also potentially indicate notification type if the app
>     generates more than one type.
> - A notification title and additional text.
> - A timestamp.

In your code, you are only setting the title. You need use the `setSmallIcon()`, `setLargeIcon()`, `setContentText()`  and `setWhen()` methods of the `NotificationCompat.Builder` instance before calling  `build()`.

Comment: But i have another question please how can i stop process to restart my service every time i kill app by long press on home button and swipe the app to kill it

Comment: See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207383/stop-android-service-when-app-is-closed-with-the-task-manager) can help you. Have a go at it yourself and if you get stuck, post another question for people to help you.