# How to execute a piece of code when app closes?

Tags: android

I would like to know how i can execute a piece of code when the app closes.
My objective is to send a cancel call to the notification so the notification is destroid when the app closes.

Comment: in `Activity.onDestory`?

Comment: either onFinish or onDestroy depending on your needs of living context.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Activity onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("SampleApp", "destroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Only if the app is killed via TakeManager otherwise is called.

Comment: my app is a music player, in which sometimes the user may close it in the taskmanager

Comment: You've no way to control that, this means that you cannot execute any code if the user closes the app via TaskManager.

Comment: then thank you for the clarification about the matter

Comment: I'd be cautious with calling code inside onDestroy(). It's not just the user via the task manager that can kill the app - the OS can kill the app if it runs low on memory. In that case onDestroy() will also not be called.

Check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210241/how-to-remove-all-notifications-when-an-android-app-activity-or-service-is-kil

Comment: @vkislicins i have found out how to do what i wanted but thank you either way :D

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207383/stop-android-service-when-app-is-closed-with-the-task-manager) , even though the process is not well documented, its a solution .

It basicly consists of creating a service that will execute an action when the the app is killed in the taskmanager.

Used [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm) as an helper to know how to create a service and then used

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    MainActivity.notification.onCancel();
    stopSelf();
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

to kill the notification and stop the service when the app was closed in the task manager

Comment: Does not work for API level >= 26, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47110577/1000551