# Background Services don't restart on Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

When the android application is killed and opened again then background services like location service and notification service don't restart in android version 8.0. They restart in android version till 7.0. I have used broadcast services to restart the services when they are stopped.

Can anyone tell me what can be used to restart the services.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background service for android oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110489/background-service-for-android-oreo)

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/keep-those-background-services-working-when-targeting-android-oreo-sdk-26-cbf6cc2bdb7f

Follow this solution.