# Can't Start Background Services in Api > 26

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-9.0-pie

trying to start a service from a background service, somehow it work with all android version Lower than api 24, and actually not work in (oreo,Pie,..).

however i try this code below, and this screen for problem i face if testing using +api>24....

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QWVq.png)

Glade for your help, Thanks!!

1) Main Activity(Start Services) :

```
 public void startService(View v) {
    String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);

    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);

     Toast.makeText(Options.this,"Notification, On.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void stopService(View v) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);

    Toast.makeText(Options.this,"Notification, Off.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

2) Background services Class :

```
package com.demo.testttt;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import static com.demo.testttt.App.CHANNEL_ID;


public class ExampleService extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Example Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        //do heavy work on a background thread
        //stopSelf();

    }
    else {

        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(ExampleService.this)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 350, 350})
                .setContentTitle("Example Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notifmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      ///  notifmanager.notify(0,notification);
        startForeground(1, notification);

    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

3) App Class :

```
package package com.demo.testttt;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;


public class App extends Application {
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    createNotificationChannel();
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Example Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
}
```

4) manifest xml :

```
    <service
        android:name=".ExampleService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110489/background-service-for-android-oreo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is Your Permission in Manifest.

you should permission of FOREGROUND_SERVICE.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```