# How to keep a service alive in Flutter to run a socket io

Tags: android, flutter, dart, service, background-service

I'm trying to create a service which will run a socket for receiver data when the app is closed.

According to this thread on Github [Flutter should provide an abstraction for background execution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671), flutter doesn't have an abstraction that executes a code in the background, so I'm writing a native code.

The service opens up correctly, but as soon as the app is closed, it gets moved to cache services and after approximately 5 minutes it is ended.

I found this [background_service MainActivity.java](https://github.com/letsdoit07/background_service/blob/master/background_service/android/app/src/main/java/com/retroportalstudio/www/background_service/MainActivity.java), but I'm not using the notification example contained in that repository. (The service contained in this repository also gets terminated once the app is closed.

The [example plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geofencing#-readme-tab-) for this [article](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) as well.

I still don't have a concrete plan to make the socket connection in the service. I actually would like to call the [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) function within the service, sort of like a callback, but I'm not sure if it will work.

So I just want to know if it is possible to keep the service running after the app is closed. If yes, how?

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.retroportalstudio.www.background_service";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent forService = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        forService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if (methodCall.method.equals("startService")) {
                    startService(forService);
                    result.success("Service Started");

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    //  @Override
    //  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //      return START_STICKY;
    //  }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not possible - you have to run foreground service (with notification), see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110489/background-service-for-android-oreo

Comment: Thanks, that works!